# How to check for ANY parameter existence in the URL?

Tags: php

When I access any `page.php` version, that contains ANY parameter, such as:

`page.php?foo=1` or `page.php?bar=3`

I want to set a value for a `$var`.

I only know how to check if a specific parameter exists:

```
if (isset($_GET['foo']))
$var = "yes";
```

But how can I check if any parameter exists?

Comment: you can also use jQuery for this, if URL contains a string

Comment: You can't rely on this.  Any part of the URL can be rewritten into a parameter -- http://example.com/foo/12345/bar.jpg might very well be "tagged" with 12345 appearing as a path.  What are you REALLY trying to do here?

Comment: rewriting is dependent on my own .htaccess, isn't it?
I want to display a certain version of the page for those who access it without any parameter, and a different version of the page for those who access it with any parameter following the `.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine the contents of the `$_GET` array as a whole:

```
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Fair point; didn't realize the performance hit was so big. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `$_GET` is not `empty`.  This is a faster call than `count`:

```
if(!empty($_GET)) {
    // parameter exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
    ...
}
```

It brings all the data existent after the `?` symbol

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is an array containing all available GET parameters.

So just cycle them with a `foreach`:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) {
    echo "$key = " . urldecode($value) . "<br />\n";
}
```

To be clear: take `foo=1` example. `$key` vill results in `foo`, while `$value` will results in `1`.